# ArcGIS Pro date handling with different specificities in one column

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, date

I have a date column in my attribute table, some of the dates are just the year, and some are the month/day/year. I made the table in excel, and when I imported it into my gdb, I specific all the data types of the columns. The dates with month/day/year are interpreted correctly, but the dates that are just the year are changed into the month/day/year format, which changes the data incorrectly.

How do I get ArcGIS Pro to correctly interpret both month/day/year and just year in one column?

Comment: Use a data type text and not data type date.

Comment: will that have any impact on querying the data in the future?

Comment: Assuming you maintain the same format for all records.  Best to use yyyy/mm/dd for full date records  and yyyy for all year records.  Maintaining this consistency will allow you to sort by chronological order and make your queries easier to write.